# Error MySql You have an error in your SQL syntax. when adding a parameter with a variable

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Syntax error when adding a parameter with textBox1.Text.I want to add a column to the database. How do I do it right. Write the correct code please

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Students ADD COLUMN ? TEXT", sqlConnection);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox1.Text); 

    try
    {
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

Screenshot https://i.paste.pics/77ce28a6fd93598b0939bc43a1d15b9a.png

Screenshot 2 result answer https://i.paste.pics/a9e8c0739bcbaf6cf7a23ca62a9c9812.png

Comment: This is not C at all. Did you mean C++?

Comment: you can't use  parameter for object name  (table and columns)

Comment: Is `'?'` a legal name for a column?

Comment: @Broman C# I just could have made a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters can't be used to modify column- or table-names. You have to build your query manually. But don't forget to escape the user-input, to avoid sql-injections:

```
string escapedStringColumnName = MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(textBox1.Text);

// Do some more validations, what text you got before building you column..
if (!new Regex("[a-zA-z ]+").IsMatch(escapedStringColumnName))
    throw new Exception();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Students ADD COLUMN `" + escapedStringColumnName + "` TEXT", sqlConnection);
```

Comment: Screenshot 2 result answer https://i.paste.pics/a9e8c0739bcbaf6cf7a23ca62a9c9812.png

Comment: You're not allowed to select a columnname with spaces. Try "asdasd" instead of "asd asd".

Comment: I need with spaces, create a column. For example, the column name will be "Next day"

Comment: You can quote columnnames with `\``. I modified the example to make it work with spaces. But be aware: Spaces can bring up problems. You have to quote every time ..